# Easy way to display a PSTMessage of java-libpst

Tags: java, pst

I basically want to index and search through a mailbox that has been saved in the .pst format. To do so, I downloaded the java-libpst library which works like a charm. But I could not find any viewer of the resulting PSTMessage object.

Long story short, I'm looking for an easy way to display PSTMessage instances that I get when using the java-libpst on a .pst file. Is there any?

Thanks by advance for your help,

Maveric78f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gui in development.  Have you tried the test code> https://code.google.com/p/java-libpst/ .  It will walk through the directory structure and print out the contents out the pst to the console.  If you want to read the boy's of the emails, just edit this line.

```
while (email != null) {
    printDepth();
    System.out.println("Email: "+email.getSubject());
    System.out.println(email.getBody());// add this line
    email = (PSTMessage)folder.getNextChild();
}
```

This library is also very powerful for getting the native html from the pst messages.
To answer your question, no.  As of right now, there is no prefabricated utility for leveraging this library to view the contents.  You may have to do that yourself.